# Ubuntu on windows

Tags: usb, windows

I am looking for Ubuntu to run from the USB on windows. I am NOT looking for a bootable USB. My university has computers running on windows and I need to work on ubuntu.

I was looking for something that lets ubuntu run on these machines.

I did come across this
http://hacknmod.com/hack/ubuntu-linux-os-thumb-drive-windows-7/

Any issues/alternatives/suggestions?

PS: Coding is all I need this for. I do need the internet while working.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, you state that you do not want a bootable USB then you link to a page about bootable USB's.  Are you looking for a way to install Ubuntu onto a USB but have it be a full install and not a LiveUSB??

Comment: I meant that I am not looking for a system that needs to be booted in order to work ie restarting the machine and boot from the USB.
And yes, it has to be a full install. On top of that I need that installation to run on windows.

Thanks.

Comment: ok, the page you linked to was for a full install but it requires booting form a USB so you cannot use bot at once. Your best option is to use VirtualBox as the answer below suggested...you will need to install the VB guest additions to get the most out of your Ubuntu VB install, this can be done with the VB menu in the virtual machine or via Ubuntu's additional drivers program(I would recommend the VB method, it is updated more often)  and as the answer stated, you will have slightly slower performance that a true install, but still enough to do most things other than gaming.ect

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to install software on the machine, you could install Oracles Virtual Box https://www.virtualbox.org . Its free software that practically emulates an operating system inside windows. There are options to make it emulate an OS from a bootable pen drive, or from a ISO disc image on the local hard drive. Please note that the machine will need to be fast enough.
If you aren't able to install software on the machine, there are portable versions available, a quick Google search turned this page: http://www.vbox.me . However I have not used this software so I cannot confirm if it works or not.
I also though I might mention that you can create bootable pen drives with Live operating systems. This makes the machine boot from the pen drive, without messing with the machines hard drive. I know you stated that  you weren't looking for a bootable pen drive, but I thought you might want to know about live operating systems :)

Comment: Thanks for the links bobsterman. I will try both the bootable and the virtual machine methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Portable Virtual Box to USB that you can run from Windows.
You can locate your virtual machine on the hard drive or on the USB.
If you locate the virtual machine on the USB it will be very slow.

http://www.vbox.me/

Also note that if Virtual Box is already installed on the computer, this can mess it up.